# Reformat nested calls to map, split, trim, etc

Tags: scala

What would be a more optimal way to format the following operation? This seems kludgy at best

I have a string that looks like this

```
val text = "$395.00 from Stylebop $185.50 from shopbop $239.00 from Intermix $335.00 from Nordstrom"
```

where am attempting to get to a Array((string,string)) where Array(shop,price)

I have the following:

```
val text = x.split("\\s\\$")
      .map(x => x.replace("$","")
      .split("from")
      .map(_.trim()))
      .map(x => (x(1),x(0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just matching with one regex:

```
"""\$([\d.]+) from ([^\$]+)""".r
    .findAllMatchIn(text)
    .map(m => (m.group(2).trim, m.group(1)))
    .toArray

// Array((Stylebop,395.00), (shopbop,185.50), (Intermix,239.00), (Nordstrom,335.00))
```